# Calculate a given determinant

Tags: determinant

I need to calculate the following determinant by using the properties of determinants.

$$\begin{vmatrix}
x & 1 & x^2 + 4x - 2\\ 
-1 & x & x^2 - 4\\ 
2 & -2 & x^2 - 2x + 4
\end{vmatrix}$$

I know that the result must be $(x^3 + x + 4)(x - 2)$, but I haven't figured out how to get it yet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could solve this without using any properties but the definition. Are you asking for tricks to find the determinant in a way that is simpler that simply using the definition?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want.

Comment: You can use Gauss-elimination or the "Entwicklungssatz" (I only know the german word) of Laplace.

Comment: Substituting $x=2$ I don't see at once that the determinant is zero and so I guess there are no obvious tricks,

Comment: @Peter, "Laplace expansion".